# How can I replace the title page of a KOMA-Scipt book with a custom one from an external PDF?

Tags: titles

I'm editing an university thesis in LyX. The university *requires* me to use their own Word template to layout the first page ([example](http://www.unibg.it/static_content/segreteria/fronteingegneriaLT.pdf)).

I have filled in their template and made a PDF out of it. I'd like that to replace the usual `maketitle` output, but the obvious approach obviously doesn't work well:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\paperwidth,height=1\paperheight]{cover.pdf}
```

This puts the PDF file in line with the text (on the second page, no less.)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Nevermind that they require you to use A4 for the thesis, but their custom template uses Letter format. . .

Comment: What about skipping the titlepage, write your document and [join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) it in the end with some program like `pdftk`, `pdfunite`, `pdfjoin`...?

Comment: @smoneck That is what I'm going to do if this doesn't work. Right now I have a kludgy `\thispagestyle{empty}\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-95,-750){\includegraphics[width=1\paperwidth,height=1\paperheight]{cover.pdf}}\end{picture}` that kinda works, though, and if I can make it work that means I don't have to do that by hand on the finalest revision.

Comment: Load the package `pdfpages` and insert the cover by `\includepdf{cover}`.

Comment: You could fake it. They probably want it to look as if you used their template. Whether it is actually produced that way is likely irrelevant. I fake Word forms regularly in TeX and all they care about is that it looks as they expect. However, for a thesis, I understand that you may not want to take the risk.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options:

1. Faking the look, like cfr proposed
2. Including usinig `\pdfpages` package

Anyway, the regular `\maketitle` must be changed or not used at all.

I decided to use `\maketitle` and redefine it, to use `\includepdf` with the front page template.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}



\let\LaTeXStandardMaketitle\maketitle

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \includepdf[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{fronteingegneriaLT.pdf}
}%

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]